# Why can't I get the return values of Json (.net mvc project)?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is supposed to be a small issue, but I am stuck here for hours.
It keeps showing 500 errors in the console. And nothing alerts out. It seems like the Json() doesn't work. I have tried a breakpoint, and tempAnswers has a list of TempAnswerModels.

class

```
public class TempAnswerModel
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

my ajax codes,

```
var sendData = { 'Id': @ViewBag.Id };
$.get('@Url.Action("LoadTempAnswers", "Questions")',sendData,function(result) {

                alert(result);
            },"json");
```

my codes in the controller,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LoadTempAnswers(int? Id)
    {
        //check if there are temp answers in the table
        var tempAnswers = TempAnswerDb.GetAllTempAnswersbyId(id);
        return Json(tempAnswers);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the GetAllTempAnswersbyId(id) is working, it seems like the Json() one doesn't work. @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 1):

Your making a GET call, and by default the ASP.NET MVC framework does not allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload to protect against an attack known as [JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).

Change the controller code to allow a GET by setting the `JsonRequestBehavior` (the default is `DenyGet`)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadTempAnswers(int? Id)
{
    var tempAnswers = TempAnswerDb.GetAllTempAnswersbyId(id);
    return Json(tempAnswers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution, would be to make the action [HttpPost], and apply the [ValidataAntiForgeryToken] attribute. You can then post the antiforgery token to the action and ensure that it is not being hijacked.

The JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet is a bit of a sledgehammer approach, as highlighted by @stephenmuecke, is there to prevent JSON Hijacking attacks.

Also, as this is a json request, you may want to make the controller action async.